# Swift: Create dictionary created inside if statement fails

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary that is different depending on a condition.  If I just pick one version of the dictionary the code runs fine.

But as soon as I try to create the dictionary inside an 'if else' statement I get a warning that dictionary is never used and subsequently in the code get a 'use of unresolved identifier datadict' error as if the dictionary was never created at all.

I'm new to swift so there is a good chance it's simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

This works:

```
let datadict: [String:Int] = [
"A":1,
"B":2,
"C":3,
"D":4,
"E":5]
```

This fails:

```
var dicttype = 1 //set the value to determine which dictionary to use

if dicttype==1 {
let datadict: [String:Int] = [
"A":1,
"B":2,
"C":3,
"D":4,
"E":5] 

} else { 

let datadict: [String:Int] = [
"A":3,
"B":2,
"C":9,
"D":4,
"E":15]  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `datadict` is scoped to the block in which it was declared (the `if`/`else`'s blocks).

To make it outlive the scope of that block, you need to *declare* it at a higher scope, and *define* it inside the narrower scope:

```
let datadict: [String: Int]
if dicttype == 1 {
    datadict = [
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
        "C": 3,
        "D": 4,
        "E": 5,
    ] 
} else { 
    datadict = [
        "A": 3,
        "B": 2,
        "C": 9,
        "D": 4,
        "E": 15,
    ]
}
```

The neat thing is that the Swift compiler enforces definitive initialization: it guarantees that all variables are initialized before their first use, in all possible code paths.

Answer (score 1):

This is the notion of **scope**, something you will have to learn and get used to in any form of programming. An `if`/`else` statement defines a scope: variables you create inside the if/else statement are only available within that scope. They get thrown away afterwards. Same reason why a variable you create inside a function isn't available inside a different function.

In this particular case, you can *declare* the variable outside the scope, and *initialize* it inside the scope:

```
let dataDict: [String: Int]
var dictType = 1
if dictType == 1 {
    dataDict = [
    ...
    ]
}
else {
    dataDict = [
    ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: I see, so in swift an 'if else' is container like a function is.  Most of my programming is in R and that is definitely not the case there.  Thank you!